# Viewをプログラムからタップする

Tags: objective-c

現在、画面上にあるボタンをタップすると、それに連動して`ImageView`も強制的にタップさせようとしているのですが、うまくいかず困っています。
タップされたコンポーネントの判定には`touchesBegan`を使ってタグで判定しています。
どうすればコードから`View`をタップすることができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 単なるタップであれば、`ImageView`のイベント内で対象の`View`に割りあてているメソッドを呼べばよいような？

Comment: `ImageView`をタップした結果何が起きるのかを差し支えない範囲で良いので記載していただけますか（画像を拡大する等）？

Comment: @fkm ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、ImageViewのイベント内というのはどういうことでしょうか？

Comment: @ita_3y ご回答ありがとうございます。タップすると画像を拡大させたいです。

Comment: @kojianu 記載ありがとうございます。画像の拡大くらいならボタンのタップイベント内で画像拡大処理を呼び出せば良いような気がしますが、それだと問題がありそうですか？

Comment: @ita_3y すみません、確かにその方法で良さそうです。難しく考えすぎていました。ありがとうございます。